# Django Multiple Views for index/dashboard template

Tags: python, django

So im trying to use my django installation to create a dashboard a combination of all the data from the 4 other models and views. For our use of django we mainly use it for stats so it's generally just pulling numbers out onto the main index page. Right now I have my index template set up as a redirect_to_template and it goes straight to a template (since everything is still static). Im trying to figure out if im going to have to create another app and pull in all the data to a new view & model for this dashboard page, or if I should create sub-templates if that would work to pull the data.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help anyone that has the question in the future. I ended up importing the apps such as

```
from status import Alert

context['list'] = Alert.objects.filter(All My Filters Here! (link below))[:8]
```

Then just for loop list in the template!

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/

Hope this is helpful to someone else!

Comment: Did you end up using class or function based views? What does your urlconf entry look like for the dashboard page?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're better of with pulling the data by using ajax from your dashboard, it will be a better UX when you have a lot of data to fetch. For that you can use one of the known 3rd party apps for creating REST API or change your existing views to deliver json response as well.

Comment: So you think use ajax to pull the data from the other live views similar to php get url but just grab just the content from between the divs that I need. Ill look into how to use REST API thanks :D!

Comment: If this helps here is a quick diagram of what I want to do http://postimg.org/image/3kmihsxlt/ Each of the 4 apps on the outside are currently standalone applications in django, I want to be able to access them from either a new app or template from /overview. Let me know if this is possible anyway. I tried to write some js to get some content from the other pages but its not working out too well.

Comment: @Joey What I meant was that you modify each of your 4 views by adding json response in addition to html response then to each url you add something like: `?format=json` or similar, so the view knows you're asking for json data. This way you achieve the goal with minimum changes to your code.